# Is there any way to align the column headings in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am extracting the data from the web, however, the data frame is showing the column headings at different rows *(Date and remaining heading are at two different rows)*. Is there any possibility to align all the headings because it is not letting me get the values for close prices in the example below:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIC9D.png)

[Extracting the close prices also showing dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUFiH.png)

Comment: Please do not insert example code and data as image. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like your data is in pivot format. You have to apply group by with required aggregate function and reset_index() to get back into actual data frame format.

Example:

```
df = df.groupby(['required column names']).sum().reset_index()
```

if you want to keep index column:

```
df = df.groupby(['required column names'],as_index=False).sum()
```

Comment: It worked in my case because I just  require the close values but somehow deleted the date column  from the data frame.

Comment: if you want index column you can try as_index=False df.groupby(['close'],as_index=False).sum()